# Swift: how to prevent duplicating code in two struct initializers conforming to the same protocol?

Tags: swift

I have a protocol that defines a simple dictionary:

```
protocol P {
    var dictionary: [String: Any] { get }
}
```

And two structs conforming to it:

```
struct S1: P {
    var moreInfo: [String]
    var dictionary: [String: Any]
}

struct S2: P {
    var dictionary: [String: Any]
}
```

I want to initialize these structs from a given object, so the initializer would be something like this:

```
init(from data: [[String: Any]]) {
    dictionary = process(data)
    // Specifically in S1
    moreInfo = moreInfoProcess(data)
}
```

What is the best solution to prevent duplicating the same code in S1 and S2 to process data and setting `dictionary` ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you just want to share `process(data)` between the two structs, @JoakimDanielson's answer shows how by making a `static` method in a protocol extension on `P`.  If you want to share the property assignments, you can't.  `dictionary` is get-only in the protocol, so a protocol extension can't initialize it.  You could delegate to another initializer, which you'd have to include in the protocol, but you have the issue that the two structs differ in their properties, and `P` doesn't know about `moreInfo`, and ultimately, *some* initializer has to be implemented in the type conforming to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to implement the common code in an extension to `P` (and make it static to avoid compilation errors)

```
extension P {
    static func process(_ data: [[String: Any]]) -> [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        // processing code...
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer by spelling, but not by concept. Swift has never implemented the missing feature of **property initializers** —so this boilerplate is the best we have.